# Moving a hidden <div> inside a scrollable <div> as the container scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css-position

I have an Angular page with the below HTML:

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; height:700px;" data-ng-if="ctrl.items.length">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr bindonce data-ng-repeat="i in ctrl.items">
                <td class="note-row">
                    <div my-tooltip-template="nav-fo-to-bo-compare/comments-hover-template.html" my-tooltip-scope="i.navSummary">
                        <div break-notes nav-summary="i.navSummary" item="i" note-disable="!ctrl.allowChanges"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The page displays a custom tooltip for each record in the table. Below is the custom tooltip directive.

```
angular.module('app').directive("myTooltipTemplate", function ($compile) {
        var contentContainer;
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                myTooltipScope: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var templateUrl = attrs.myTooltipTemplate;

                scope.hidden = true;

                var tooltipElement = angular.element("<div class='customTooltip' ng-hide='hidden'>");
                tooltipElement.append("<div ng-include='\"" + templateUrl + "\"'></div>");

                element.parent().append(tooltipElement);
                element
                  .on('mouseenter', function () { scope.hidden = false; scope.$digest(); })
                  .on('mouseleave', function () { scope.hidden = true; scope.$digest(); });

                var toolTipScope = scope.$new(true);
                angular.extend(toolTipScope, scope.myTooltipScope);
                $compile(tooltipElement.contents())(toolTipScope);
                $compile(tooltipElement)(scope);
            }
        };
    });
```

Custom tooltip CSS class:

```
.customTooltip{
            position:absolute;            
            background-color:#00adee;
            z-index:2; 
            display:block;
            right: 25px;       
        }
```

The tooltip appear properly positioned for the records that show up on the screen. It shows up on mousehover. However, when I scroll the page to view the records towards end of the table, the custom tooltip appears to be still showing up at a position where the that table record was originally present. How can I ensure that even when the user scrolls the table, the tooltips from the bottom rows will appear just as the tooltips at the top of the grid ?

Comment: That is because you have `position:absolute;` in your CSS. What will happen if you remove that?

Comment: If I remove the position attribute from the CSS, the tooltip appears in line with the row even when I scroll, but this time it expands the row and distorts the UI. Doesn't exactly look like a tooltip then.

Comment: ok.. then keep that `absolute` itself. Try adding `position:relative` to the parent..

Comment: by parent, do you mean on <td class="note-row"> ??

Comment: might be...because i dont know which one exactly is `customTooltip`..try it..

Comment: hey that worked. although the tooltip now stretches vertically :(

Comment: stretches vertically? how...didnt get you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103883/discussion-between-lucifer-and-lal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
position:relative
```

to the parent container of the absolutley positioned `div`. That is, add `position:relative` to the div with class `note-row`.

More details can be found in this [tutorial](http://cssreset.com/understanding-css-relative-and-absolute-positioning-explained/)